# Error uploading file with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, retrofit, multipartform-data, retrofit2

The system I am working has an end point that receives a file picture in order to set user's profile picture. If I try sending it via Postman, everything works fine:

[image]

When I try to upload it from my App using retrofit it always fail. Code + stacktrace is below:

Server side code:

```
begin
         user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
         image = params[:image]
         attachment = {
             :filename => image[:filename],
             :type => image[:type],
             :headers => image[:head],
             :tempfile => image[:tempfile]
         }

         image_link = ""
         if params[:upload_type] == "profile"
           user.profile_image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(attachment)
           image_link = get_image_path(user.id,params[:upload_type],"original",attachment[:filename])
           user.image_profile_original = get_image_path(user.id,params[:upload_type],"original",attachment[:filename])
           user.image_profile_large = get_image_path(user.id,params[:upload_type],"large",attachment[:filename])
```

---

```
 /*e22*/
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/upload_image")
    fun uploadUserImage(@Header("Authorization") authHeader: String,  @Part("upload_type") description: RequestBody, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part): Call<ResponseWrapper>
```

---

```
 fun uploadUserImage(image: Uri) {
        val source = File(image.path)
        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContext().contentResolver.getType(image)), source)
        val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "profile", requestFile)
        val description = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, "profile")
        mMessenger.uploadUserImage(getAuthorizationHeader(), description, body).enqueue(ResponseWrapperCallback(EventCatalog.e0022))
    }
```

Request response:

```
E/ResponseWrapperCallback: Failed processing request: profile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ResponseWrapperCallback: HTTP request mapped to event e0022 finished with error
```

---

## Edit 1

I do think that this error has something to do with how the File object is being instantiated. If I create the file straight from the Uri, its real path seems not to be sent to server. I say that because of the error log above, it says that it doesn't located the file on the retrieved device's Uri. I've tried to extract file's real path from the Uri, however, error log from server has changed to:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Marvel/Media/Characters/Adam Warlock.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The way I'm instantiating the File object with the real file path is like that:

```
   private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String {
        val result: String
        val cursor = getContext().contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor == null) {
            result = contentURI.path
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
            result = cursor.getString(idx)
            cursor.close()
        }
        return result
    }

//....

val source = File(getRealPathFromURI(Uri))
```

## Edit 2

As per user Anurag Singh request, below is the Manifest and OS information:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

---

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

---

## Edit 3

This is the code generated by Postman which works fine!

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"sample 2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_type\"\r\n\r\nprofile\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://********/user/upload_image")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
  .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer ******")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "******")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Post, the value of source.

Comment: Hi @AnuragSingh what part of it would you like to see? I could notice that if I create the file directly from Uri, its real path is not sent to the server. When I try t extract file's real path from Uri and create the object from it, serve error has changed to: /storage/emulated/0/Marvel/Media/Characters/Adam Warlock.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: source means file path. I wanted to check the how fetching path from URI. Now based on the new error which is related to permission. Let me know the device os version on which you are testing, post the manifest permissions and the values of the following compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion. Thanks

Comment: Please, checkout the edits I've made to the question

Comment: Try adding  the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. In the mean time let me do more analysis. Also make sure that Content-Type set for file upload is set to multipart/form-data and not application/json if you intercept the underlying OkHttp client.

Comment: @Anurag Singh you've saved my. The problem was permission. I had to request it using Android M, and I had to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL to make it work. All working fine now! Thank you very much!

Comment: So should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, post it please!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>.
```

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.
>   [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me on this not very straight forward issue